# Foreign Key (Chave Estrageira) em Java

Tags: java, foreign-keys, dao

I'm trying to add a patient to my system, but in order to be able to add it, I need to have the primary phone and address key. I've tried several methods that I saw on youtube and attempts with ChatGPT but I was not successful, the only message I received is that it was not possible to find the codTel and codEndereco.

**TelefoneDAO.java**

```
package model.dao;

import database.ConexaoBD;
import java.sql.*;
import model.bean.Telefone;

public class TelefoneDAO {
    private int generatedKey; // Variável para armazenar a chave gerada

    public void createTelefone(Telefone telefone) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement create = null;

        try {
            //Obtem conexão com o banco de dados
            conn = ConexaoBD.obtemConexao();
            //Preparando o SQL para o inserir Paciente
            String sql = "INSERT INTO telefone_paciente (celular) VALUES (?)";
            create = conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            create.setString(1, telefone.getNumero());
            //Executa a inserção
            create.executeUpdate();
            // Obtém a chave gerada
            ResultSet generatedKeys = create.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                generatedKey = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("ID gerado do telefone: " + generatedKey);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Telefone inserido com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao inserir paciente: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }

    public int getGeneratedKey() {
        return generatedKey;
    }
}
```

**EnderecoDAO.java**

```
package model.dao;

import database.ConexaoBD;
import java.sql.*;
import model.bean.Endereco;

public class EnderecoDAO {

    private int generatedKey; // Variável para armazenar a chave gerada

    public void createEndereco(Endereco endereco) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement create = null;

        try {
            //Obtem conexão com o banco de dados
            conn = ConexaoBD.obtemConexao();
            //Preparando o SQL para o inserir Paciente
            String sql = "INSERT INTO endereco_paciente (rua, bairro, cidade, estado, cep) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            create = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            create.setString(1, endereco.getRua());
            create.setString(2, endereco.getBairro());
            create.setString(3, endereco.getCidade());
            create.setString(4, endereco.getEstado());
            create.setInt(5, endereco.getCep());
            //Executa a inserção
            create.executeUpdate();
            // Obtém a chave gerada
            ResultSet generatedKeys = create.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                generatedKey = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("ID gerado do endereço: " + generatedKey);
            }
            System.out.println("Endereço inserido com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao inserir paciente: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int getGeneratedKey() {
        return generatedKey;
    }
}
```

**PacienteDAO.java**

```
package model.dao;

import model.bean.Paciente;
import database.ConexaoBD;
import java.sql.*;

public class PacienteDAO {
//CRUD
    public boolean createPaciente(Paciente paciente) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement create = null;

        try {
            // Obter conexão com o banco de dados
            conn = ConexaoBD.obtemConexao();

            // Preparando o SQL para inserir o Paciente
            String sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (nome, cpf, email, senha, cod_tel, cod_endereco) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            create = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            // Parametros de valor para create
            create.setString(1, paciente.getNome());
            create.setInt(2, paciente.getCpf());
            create.setString(3, paciente.getEmail());
            create.setString(4, paciente.getSenha());
            create.setInt(5, paciente.getTelefone().getCodTel());
            create.setInt(6, paciente.getEndereco().getCodEndereco());

            // Executa a inserção
            create.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Paciente inserido com sucesso!");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao inserir paciente: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            // Fecha os recursos
            if (create != null) {
                create.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Pessoa.java**

```
package model.bean;

public abstract class Pessoa {
    
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;

    //Construtor
    public Pessoa() {
    }

    public Pessoa(String nome, String email, String senha) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Pessoa(String email, String senha) {
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    //Getters & Setters
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

**Paciente.java**

```
model.bean;
public class Paciente extends Pessoa {

    private int cpf;
    private Telefone telefone;
    private Endereco endereco;

    //Construtor
    
    /*DAO*/
    public Paciente(String nome, int cpf, String email, String senha) {
        super(nome, email, senha);
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    //Getters & Setters
    public int getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(int cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public void setTelefone(Telefone telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Telefone getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

}
```

**Endereco.java**

```
package model.bean;

public abstract class Endereco {

    private int codEndereco;
    private String rua;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private int cep;

    //Construtor
    public Endereco() {
    }

    public Endereco(int codEndereco, String rua, String bairro, String cidade, String estado, int cep) {
        this.codEndereco = codEndereco;
        this.rua = rua;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.cep = cep;
    }
    //Getters & Setters

    public int getCodEndereco() {
        return codEndereco;
    }

    public void setCodEndereco(int codEndereco) {
        this.codEndereco = codEndereco;
    }

    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public int getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(int cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

}
```

**Telefone.java**

```
package model.bean;

public abstract class Telefone {

    private int codTel;
    private String numero;

    //Construtor
    public Telefone() {
    }
    
    public Telefone(int codTel, String numero) {
        this.codTel = codTel;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    //Getters & Setters
    public int getCodTel() {
        return codTel;
    }

    public void setCodTel(int codTel) {
        this.codTel = codTel;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

}
```

I'm using this method to get the data
**Paciente.java(form)**

```
private void btnProximaTelaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // Identificando Dados Inseridos
        String nome = txtNome.getText();
        String email = txtEmail.getText();
        int cpf = Integer.parseInt(txtCpf.getText());
        String senha1 = new String(senhaPasswordField1.getPassword());
        String senha2 = new String(senhaPasswordField2.getPassword());

        try {
            if (senha1.equals(senha2)) {
                Paciente paciente = new Paciente(nome, cpf, email, senha1);
                PacienteDAO pacientedao = new PacienteDAO();
                pacientedao.createPaciente(paciente);
                System.out.println("Paciente inserido com sucesso");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserido com sucesso.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Suas senhas estão diferentes. Tente novamente.");
            }
            System.out.println("Dados Salvos com sucesso");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possível inserir: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**Telefone.java(form)**

```
private void btnCriarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        String celular = txtCelular.getText();
        String celular1 = txtCelular1.getText();
        try {
            if (celular.equals(celular1)) {
                Telefone telefone = new Telefone(0,celular) {
                };
                TelefoneDAO telefonedao = new TelefoneDAO();
                telefonedao.createTelefone(telefone);
                System.out.println("Telefone cadastrado. Aguardando outros dados.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Números não coincidem. Tente novamente.");
            }
            InsertAddressPaciente clickNextPage = new InsertAddressPaciente();
            clickNextPage.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel inserir" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Endereco.java(form)**

```
private void btnCriarContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        //Identificando Dados Inseridos
        String rua = txtRua.getText();
        String bairro = txtBairro.getText();
        String cidade = txtCidade.getText();
        String estado = txtEstado.getText();
        int cep = Integer.parseInt(txtCep.getText());
        try {
            Endereco endereco = new Endereco(0,rua, bairro, cidade, estado, cep) {};
            EnderecoDAO enderecodao = new EnderecoDAO();
            enderecodao.createEndereco(endereco);
            InsertPersonalDataPaciente clickNextPage = new InsertPersonalDataPaciente();
            clickNextPage.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("Enderço Salvos com sucesso.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel inserir");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your SQL in your PreparedStatement have exactly the same column names as the columns in your database tables?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _the only message I received is that it was not possible to find the codTel and codEndereco_ I think that's because you're only printing a message in your `catch` blocks. You should add `e.printStackTrace();` to your `catch` blocks. Then, if you still don't know how to fix your problem, [edit] your question and post the stack trace[s]. The way it is now - even though you translated your question to English - it is still not clear what your problem is and a stack trace would help me to understand what your problem is.